# UIActivityViewController and Notes

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have UIActivityViewController in my app for things like posting to Facebook, but it also adds in Notes as an option, but since there is no UIActivityType for Notes, I cannot exclude it, but it also adds nothing to the Notes.  My code is:

```
Mail *mail = [[Mail alloc]init];
    NSString *html = self.finalObject[@"Request"];
    NSString *thetitle = [self.finalObject[@"Title"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *thedate = self.finalObject[@"dateMade"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM_dd_yyyy"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *theNewDate1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:thedate];
    NSString *theNewDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:theNewDate1];

    mail.thehtml = html;
    self.nameofhtmlfile = [[[[@"http://www.iprayed4u.net/app/" stringByAppendingString:thetitle] stringByAppendingString:@"_"] stringByAppendingString:theNewDate] stringByAppendingString:@".html"];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self] applicationActivities:@[mail]];



        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,

                                              UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,

                                              UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                              UIActivityTypeMail,
                                              UIActivityTypePrint,
                                              UIActivityTypeAirDrop
                                              ];



    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {

    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]){
        NSString *test = [[@"I just pledged to pray.  You can pray too, just click " stringByAppendingString:self.nameofhtmlfile] stringByAppendingString:@" to view request.  Get #iPrayed4U here https://appsto.re/us/p_t30.i"];
        return test;
    }
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]){
        NSString *test = [[[[[@"'" stringByAppendingString:self.finalObject[@"Title"]] stringByAppendingString:@"'.  "] stringByAppendingString:@"I just pledged to pray.  You can pray too, just click " ] stringByAppendingString:self.nameofhtmlfile] stringByAppendingString:@" to view request.  You can also get the app for free.  Check out iPrayed 4 U on iOS at https://appsto.re/us/p_t30.i #iPrayed4U"];
        return test;
    }
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]){
        NSString *test = [[[[[@"'" stringByAppendingString:self.finalObject[@"Title"]] stringByAppendingString:@"'.  "] stringByAppendingString:@"I just pledged to pray.  You can pray too, just click " ] stringByAppendingString:self.nameofhtmlfile] stringByAppendingString:@" to view request.  You can also get the app for free.  Check out iPrayed 4 U on iOS at https://appsto.re/us/p_t30.i #iPrayed4U"];
        return test;
    }
    return nil;
}
- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return @"Some string";
}
```

How can I either get it to remove Notes from the UIActivityViewController, or get it to actually work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot exclude Notes because it is not a system activity: it is a Share Extension. Only the user can decide whether to include it or exclude it.

Now that you've added the rest of your code, you can see why Notes doesn't save anything: you are not handing it any data. You are returning `nil` when Notes asks for the data:

```
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]){
    }
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]){
    }
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]){
    }
    return nil; // this is what you are sending to Notes
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put in the other method in my code, will add that to OP now.

Comment: Now that I've read your code I can answer the second part too. :)))

Comment: Thanks for that, but since there is no activity type for notes, how are you supposed to pass anything to it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You have promised to provide an NSString. Provide one.

Comment: Read the docs: "May be nil if multiple items were registered for a single activity type, so long as one of the items returns an actual value." You are only registering one item, so you _must not_ return `nil`. You must return an NSString. Remember, you have no idea what share extensions will appear here. They will all be expecting an NSString, because that is what you have promised. You need to be a good citizen. :(

Comment: What I get for trusting tutorials to show me how to do something.  No shortcuts, thanks.

Comment: Well, be fair. Share extensions started in iOS 8. Your tutorial may not have known they would come along and change the world.

Comment: Note that you can detect that this is Notes if you want to; it has `activityType` "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension".